# tailwindcss class is overridden by the parent element

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a reusable button style variant made with tailwindcss:

gradient: 'relative before:absolute before:w-full before:h-full before:-z-10 before:bg-gradient-to-tr before:from-gradient-primary before:to-gradient-secondary before:left-0 before:top-0 before:blur-[10px] before:translate-y-1 before:opacity-60 bg-gradient-to-tr from-gradient-primary to-gradient-secondary text-primary-foreground text-white hover:from-gradient-primary/90 hover:to-gradient-secondary/90',

The style includes a blur backdrop. If I want to use it and assign, for example, bg-secondary on the parent div where the button is in, the backdrop gets removed. As soon as I remove the bg-secondary it's working again.

Is there a fix for this?

Code:

```html
<div className='bg-secondary'>
  <Button variant={'gradient'}>
    Upgrade
  </Button>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider reformatting your post. It seems some of the code may have been lost since you did not format it as a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering with the backdrop being removed when applying the bg-secondary class to the parent div is likely due to the stacking context and how the before pseudo-element is positioned.

To address this issue, you can try the following approach:

1. Adjust the stacking context:

Add relative positioning to the parent div that has the bg-secondary class. This will establish a new stacking context for its children.
Update the relative positioning to relative z-10 to ensure that the parent div remains above the before pseudo-element.
Example:

```
<div className='relative z-10 bg-secondary'>
  <Button variant={'gradient'}>Upgrade</Button>
</div>
```

2. Modify the before pseudo-element styles:

Add z-[-1] to the before pseudo-element to position it behind the parent div.
Adjust the opacity value to control the desired level of transparency for the backdrop.
Example:

```
gradient: 'relative before:absolute before:w-full before:h-full before:-z-1 before:bg-gradient-to-tr before:from-gradient-primary before:to-gradient-secondary before:left-0 before:top-0 before:blur-[10px] before:translate-y-1 before:opacity-40 bg-gradient-to-tr from-gradient-primary to-gradient-secondary text-primary-foreground text-white hover:from-gradient-primary/90 hover:to-gradient-secondary/90',
```

By modifying the stacking context and adjusting the before pseudo-element styles, you should be able to maintain the backdrop effect while applying the bg-secondary class to the parent div.

Comment: Thank you so much! The first one already fixed it. Appreciate the help

Comment: Good to hear that.
I will help you further. :)